# Computational complexity of numerical integration of gaussian function

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, computational-complexity

$ \int^{b}_{a} \exp(-x^2)\,dx$.

I have the following two questions regarding the above integral expression of the Gaussian function:

1. Is there a numerical method we can use to solve the above integral? It doesn't have to be the most efficient method.
2. Would there be a way to determine the computational complexity of such a numerical method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean $$\int^{b}_{a}  \exp(-x^2)\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2} \Big(\text{erf}(b)-\text{erf}(a)\Big)$$ This comes from the definition of the ${erf}$ function.

At http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function, you will find approximation methods of different complexities.

Comment: That was very helpful indeed. Wonder why I didn't think of that in terms of erf function before.